# IndexError: list assignment index out of range (Python)

Tags: python, list

please consider the following code:

```py
def getString(absA, y):
    i = 0
    t = list(range(100))
    while absA > 0:
        t[i] = absA % y
        absA = absA / y
        i = i + 1  
    for j in range(len(t)):
        if t[j] == '10':
            t[j] = 'A'
        elif t[j] == '11':
            t[j] = 'B'
        elif t[j] == '12':
            t[j] = 'C'
        elif t[j] == '13':
            t[j] = 'D'
        elif t[j] == '14':
            t[j] = 'E'
        elif t[j] == '15':
            t[j] = 'F'
    return t

bitString = getString(abs(eval(a)), eval(b))
```

I guess it's some simple things I don't know.Why does this list go out of range?

Comment: what you want to do with the code.?

Answer (score 0):

You go out of range because this loop in particular never checks if `i` might exceed the bounds of the list `t`.

```
while absA > 0:
    t[i] = absA % y
    absA = absA / y
    i = i + 1
```

**Code Note:**

Your comparisons of the form:

```
if t[j] == '10': ...
```

will not do what you hope they will do.  The element `t[j]` is a **number** not a string.

Answer (score 0):

`while absA > 0:` is an infinite loop and after too many rotations returns the error you get. It's a logical error.